# Connection closed before request completed - Android ION

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-networking, android-ion

```
(113 ms) https://usermap.cvut.cz/photos/simekada: Connection error
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): connection closed before response completed.
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): java.lang.Exception: connection closed before response completed.
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpResponseImpl$3.onCompleted(AsyncHttpResponseImpl.java:68)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.report(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:335)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.write(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:277)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.handleResult(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:181)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.access$000(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:17)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncSSLSocketWrapper$1.onDataAvailable(AsyncSSLSocketWrapper.java:91)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.BufferedDataEmitter.onDataAvailable(BufferedDataEmitter.java:33)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.BufferedDataEmitter.onDataAvailable(BufferedDataEmitter.java:61)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:20)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncNetworkSocket.onReadable(AsyncNetworkSocket.java:169)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:805)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:664)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$700(AsyncServer.java:34)
E/MyLogs  ( 4650): at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:612)
```

I load the image with following code called from fragment onCreateView method. The fragment is attached to navigation drawer view..

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_profile_picture);

        if (userAccount.getAuthToken() != null) {
            String username = userAccount.getUsername();
            String url = "https://usermap.cvut.cz/photos/" + username;
            Ion.getDefault(getActivity()).setLogging("MyLogs", Log.DEBUG);

            Ion.with(getActivity(), url)
                    .withBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person)
                    .error(R.drawable.lion)
                    .intoImageView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately not..I decided to use Picasso instead of ion..It works better for me..not perfect, but better:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind checking, I think the underlying cause of this bug was fixed recently:

https://github.com/koush/ion/issues/18
https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync/issues/55

Was related to SSL.